# How to create custom ExtJS form field component?

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4

I want to create custom ExtJS **form field** components using other ExtJS components in it (e.g. TreePanel). How can I do it most easily?

I've read docs of [Ext.form.field.Base](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Base) but I don't want to define field body by `fieldSubTpl`. I just want to write code which creates ExtJS components and maybe some other code which gets and sets values.

**Update:** Summarized purposes are the followings:

- This new component should fit in the
  form GUI as a field. It should have
  label and the same alignment (label,
  anchor) of other fields without need
  of further hacking.
- Possibly, I have
  to write some getValue, setValue
  logic. I'd rather embed it into this component than making separated code which copies things into further hidden form fields that I also have to manage.

Comment: You might want to look at the ItemSelector extension which does exactly that.

Comment: Similar question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092112/ext-ux-form-field-datetime-questions

Comment: what do you want it to do other than being a form field?

Answer (score 29):

To extend @RobAgar 's answer, following a really simple Date Time field that I wrote for ExtJS 3 and it's quickport that I made for ExtJS 4. The important thing is the use of the [`Ext.form.field.Field`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field) mixin. This mixin provides a common interface for the logical behavior and state of form fields, including:

Getter and setter methods for field values
Events and methods for tracking value and validity changes
Methods for triggering validation

This can be used for combining multiple fields and let act them as one. For a total custom fieldtype I recommend to extend [`Ext.form.field.Base`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base)

Here is the example that I mentioned above. It should shoe how easy this can be done even for something like a date object where we need to format the data within the getter and setter.

```
Ext.define('QWA.form.field.DateTime', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
    mixins: {
        field: 'Ext.form.field.Field'
    },
    alias: 'widget.datetimefield',
    layout: 'hbox',
    width: 200,
    height: 22,
    combineErrors: true,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    submitFormat: 'c',

    dateCfg: null,
    timeCfg: null,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.dateCfg) me.dateCfg = {};
        if (!me.timeCfg) me.timeCfg = {};
        me.buildField();
        me.callParent();
        me.dateField = me.down('datefield')
        me.timeField = me.down('timefield')

        me.initField();
    },

    //@private
    buildField: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.items = [
        Ext.apply({
            xtype: 'datefield',
            submitValue: false,
            format: 'd.m.Y',
            width: 100,
            flex: 2
        }, me.dateCfg),
        Ext.apply({
            xtype: 'timefield',
            submitValue: false,
            format: 'H:i',
            width: 80,
            flex: 1
        }, me.timeCfg)]
    },

    getValue: function () {
        var me = this,
            value,
            date = me.dateField.getSubmitValue(),
            dateFormat = me.dateField.format,
            time = me.timeField.getSubmitValue(),
            timeFormat = me.timeField.format;
        if (date) {
            if (time) {
                value = Ext.Date.parse(date + ' ' + time, me.getFormat());
            } else {
                value = me.dateField.getValue();
            }
        }
        return value;
    },

    setValue: function (value) {
        var me = this;
        me.dateField.setValue(value);
        me.timeField.setValue(value);
    },

    getSubmitData: function () {
        var me = this,
            data = null;
        if (!me.disabled && me.submitValue && !me.isFileUpload()) {
            data = {},
            value = me.getValue(),
            data[me.getName()] = '' + value ? Ext.Date.format(value, me.submitFormat) : null;
        }
        return data;
    },

    getFormat: function () {
        var me = this;
        return (me.dateField.submitFormat || me.dateField.format) + " " + (me.timeField.submitFormat || me.timeField.format)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 25):

Now that's cool. The other day, I created a fiddle to answer another question before realizing I was off-topic. And here your are, finally bringing to my attention the question to my answer. Thanks!

So, here are the steps required in implementing a custom field from another component:

1. Creating the child component
2. Render the child component
3. Ensuring the child component is sized and resized correctly
4. Getting and setting value
5. Relaying events

### Creating the child component

The first part, creating the component, is easy. There's nothing particular compared to creating a component for any other usage.

However, you must create the child in the parent field's `initComponent` method (and not at rendering time). This is because external code can legitimately expect that all dependent objects of a component are instantiated after `initComponent` (e.g. to add listeners to them).

Furthermore, you can be kind to yourself and create the child before calling the super method. If you create the child after the super method, you may get a call to your field's `setValue` method (see bellow) at a time when the child is not yet instantiated.

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.childComponent = Ext.create(...);
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

As you see, I am creating a single component, which is what you'll want in most case. But you can also want to go fancy and compose multiple child components. In this case, I think it would be clever to back to well known territories as quickly as possible: that is, create one container as the child component, and compose in it.

### Rendering

Then comes the question of rendering. At first I considered using [`fieldSubTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-fieldSubTpl) to render a container div, and have the child component render itself in it. However, we don't need the template features in that case, so we can as well bypass it completely using the [`getSubTplMarkup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-getSubTplMarkup) method.

I explored other components in Ext to see how they manage the rendering of child components. I found a good example in BoundList and its paging toolbar (see the [code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/BoundList.html#Ext-view-BoundList-cfg-renderTpl)). So, in order to obtain the child component's markup, we can use [`Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractHelper-method-generateMarkup) in combination with the child's [`getRenderTree`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-getRenderTree) method.

So, here's the implementation of `getSubTplMarkup` for our field:

```
getSubTplMarkup: function() {
    // generateMarkup will append to the passed empty array and return it
    var buffer = Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(this.childComponent.getRenderTree(), []);
    // but we want to return a single string
    return buffer.join('');
}
```

Now, that's not enough. The [code of BoundList](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/BoundList.html#Ext-view-BoundList-method-finishRenderChildren) learns us that there's another important part in component rendering: calling the [`finishRender()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-finishRender) method of the child component. Fortunately, our custom field will have its own [`finishRenderChildren`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-finishRenderChildren) method called just when that needs to be done.

```
finishRenderChildren: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.childComponent.finishRender();
}
```

### Resizing

Now our child will be rendered in the right place, but it will not respect its parent field size. That is especially annoying in the case of a form field, because that means it won't honor the anchor layout.

That's very straightforward to fix, we just need to resize the child when the parent field is resized. From my experience, this is something that was greatly improved since Ext3. Here, we just need to not forget the extra space for the label:

```
onResize: function(w, h) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.childComponent.setSize(w - this.getLabelWidth(), h);
}
```

### Handling value

This part will, of course, depend on your child component(s), and the field you're creating. Moreover, from now on, it's just a matter of using your child components in a regular way, so I won't detail this part too much.

A minima, you also need to implement the [`getValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-getValue) and [`setValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-setValue) methods of your field. That will make the [`getFieldValues`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getFieldValues) method of the form work, and that will be enough to load/update records from the form.

To handle validation, you must implement [`getErrors`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-getErrors). To polish this aspect, you may want to add a handful of CSS rules to visually represent the invalid state of your field.

Then, if you want your field to be usable in a form that will be submitted as an actual form (as opposed to with an AJAX request), you'll need [`getSubmitValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-getSubmitValue) to return a value that can be casted to a string without damage.

Apart from that, as far as I know, you don't have to worry about the concept or [raw value](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base) introduced by `Ext.form.field.Base` since that's only used to handle the representation of the value in an actual input element. With our Ext component as input, we're way off that road!

### Events

Your last job will be to implement the events for your fields. You will probably want to fire the three events of `Ext.form.field.Field`, that is [`change`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-event-change), `dirtychange` and `validitychange`.

Again, the implementation will be very specific to the child component you use and, to be honest, I haven't explored this aspect too much. So I'll let you wire this for yourself.

My preliminary conclusion though, is that `Ext.form.field.Field` offers to do all the heavy lifting for you, provided that (1) you call [`checkChange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-checkChange) when needed, and (2) [`isEqual`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-isEqual) implementation is working with your field's value format.

### Example: TODO list field

Finally, here's a complete code example, using a grid to represent a TODO list field.

You can see it [live on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/7GKmt/), where I tries to show that the field behaves in an orderly manner.

```
Ext.define('My.form.field.TodoList', {
    // Extend from Ext.form.field.Base for all the label related business
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base'

    ,alias: 'widget.todolist'

    // --- Child component creation ---

    ,initComponent: function() {

        // Create the component

        // This is better to do it here in initComponent, because it is a legitimate 
        // expectationfor external code that all dependant objects are created after 
        // initComponent (to add listeners, etc.)

        // I will use this.grid for semantical access (value), and this.childComponent
        // for generic issues (rendering)
        this.grid = this.childComponent = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            hideHeaders: true
            ,columns: [{dataIndex: 'value', flex: 1}]
            ,store: {
                fields: ['value']
                ,data: []
            }
            ,height: this.height || 150
            ,width: this.width || 150

            ,tbar: [{
                text: 'Add'
                ,scope: this
                ,handler: function() {
                    var value = prompt("Value?");
                    if (value !== null) {
                        this.grid.getStore().add({value: value});
                    }
                }
            },{
                text: "Remove"
                ,itemId: 'removeButton'
                ,disabled: true // initial state
                ,scope: this
                ,handler: function() {
                    var grid = this.grid,
                        selModel = grid.getSelectionModel(),
                        store = grid.getStore();
                    store.remove(selModel.getSelection());
                }
            }]

            ,listeners: {
                scope: this
                ,selectionchange: function(selModel, selection) {
                    var removeButton = this.grid.down('#removeButton');
                    removeButton.setDisabled(Ext.isEmpty(selection));
                }
            }
        });

        // field events
        this.grid.store.on({
            scope: this
            ,datachanged: this.checkChange
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

    // --- Rendering ---

    // Generates the child component markup and let Ext.form.field.Base handle the rest
    ,getSubTplMarkup: function() {
        // generateMarkup will append to the passed empty array and return it
        var buffer = Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(this.childComponent.getRenderTree(), []);
        // but we want to return a single string
        return buffer.join('');
    }

    // Regular containers implements this method to call finishRender for each of their
    // child, and we need to do the same for the component to display smoothly
    ,finishRenderChildren: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.childComponent.finishRender();
    }

    // --- Resizing ---

    // This is important for layout notably
    ,onResize: function(w, h) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.childComponent.setSize(w - this.getLabelWidth(), h);
    }

    // --- Value handling ---

    // This part will be specific to your component of course

    ,setValue: function(values) {
        var data = [];
        if (values) {
            Ext.each(values, function(value) {
                data.push({value: value});
            });
        }
        this.grid.getStore().loadData(data);
    }

    ,getValue: function() {
        var data = [];
        this.grid.getStore().each(function(record) {
            data.push(record.get('value'));
        });
        return data;        
    }

    ,getSubmitValue: function() {
        return this.getValue().join(',');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Heh. After posting the bounty I found out that `Ext.form.FieldContainer` isn't just a *field* container, but a fully fledged *component* container, so there is a simple solution.

All you need to do is extend `FieldContainer`, overriding `initComponent` to add the child components, and implement `setValue`, `getValue` and the validation methods as appropriate for your value data type.

Here's an example with a grid whose value is a list of name/value pair objects:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.widget.MyGridField', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
  alias: 'widget.mygridfield',

  layout: 'fit',

  initComponent: function()
  {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.valueGrid = Ext.widget({
      xtype: 'grid',
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'value'],
        data: this.value
      }),
      columns: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          flex: 3
        },
        {
          text: 'Value',
          dataIndex: 'value',
          flex: 1
        }
      ]
    });

    this.add(this.valueGrid);
  },

  setValue: function(value)
  {
    this.valueGrid.getStore().loadData(value);
  },

  getValue: function()
  {
    // left as an exercise for the reader :P
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rob I think you forgot a important thing; the `Ext.form.field.Field` mixin. I added a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17059073/701988) with a example how to use it. Much the same like yours but it was easier to post it then to add all to comments of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a few times.  Here is the general process/pseudo-code I use:

- Create an extension of field that provides the most useful re-use (typically Ext.form.TextField if you just want to get/set a string value)
- In the `afterrender` of the field, hide the textfield, and create a wrapping element around this.el with `this.wrap = this.resizeEl = this.positionEl = this.el.wrap()`
- Render any components to `this.wrap` (e.g. using `renderTo: this.wrap` in the config)
- Override `getValue` and `setValue` to talk to the component(s) you rendered manually
- You may need to do some manually sizing in a `resize` listener if your form's layout changes
- Don't forget to cleanup any components you create in the `beforeDestroy` method!

I can't wait to switch our codebase to ExtJS 4, where these kinds of things are easy.

Good luck!

Comment: They're not easy in Ext 4 - that's why he's asking for an EXT 4 Example :D

Comment: Not sure if the question was tagged later with Ext4, but in that version, it should be as easy as using the `Ext.form.field.Field` mixin, and overriding your `getValue` and `setValue`.  Although I haven't had to do this yet, but I know that is the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was asked rather vague - I only can provide the basic pattern for ExtJS v4.

Even if it's not too specific, it has the advance that it's rather universal like this:

```
Ext.define('app.view.form.field.CustomField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    requires: [
        /* require further components */
    ],

    /* custom configs & callbacks */

    getValue: function(v){
        /* override function getValue() */
    },

    setValue: function(v){
        /* override function setValue() */
    },

    getSubTplData: [
       /* most likely needs to be overridden */
    ],

    initComponent: function(){

        /* further code on event initComponent */

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The file /ext/src/form/field/Base.js provides the names of all configs and functions that can be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Following the documentation at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Base

This code will create a reusable TypeAhead/Autocomplete style field for selecting a language.

```
var langs = Ext.create( 'Ext.data.store', {
    fields: [ 'label', 'code' ],
    data: [
        { code: 'eng', label: 'English' },
        { code: 'ger', label: 'German' },
        { code: 'chi', label: 'Chinese' },
        { code: 'ukr', label: 'Ukranian' },
        { code: 'rus', label: 'Russian' }
    ]
} );

Ext.define( 'Ext.form.LangSelector', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.LangSelector',
    allowBlank: false,
    hideTrigger: true,
    width: 225,
    displayField: 'label',
    valueField: 'code',
    forceSelection: true,
    minChars: 1,
    store: langs
} );
```

You can use the field in a form simply by setting the xtype to the widget name:

```
{
    xtype: 'LangSelector'
    fieldLabel: 'Language',
    name: 'lang'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really qualify as a custom form field - it's just a combo box with a set of defined defaults applied.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers either use the Mixin Ext.form.field.Field or just extends on some already made class that suits their needs - which is fine.

But I do not recommend fully overwriting the setValue method, that is IMO really bad form!

A lot more happens than just setting and getting the value, and if you fully overwrite it - well you will for instance mess up the dirty state, processing of rawValue etc..

Two options here I guess, one is to callParent(arguments) inside the method you declare to keep things streamlined, or to at the end when you are done apply the inherited method from where ever you got it (mixin or extend).

But do not just overwrite it with no regards for what that already made method does behind the scenes.

Also remember that if you use other field types in your new class - then do set the isFormField property to false - otherwise your getValues method on the form will take those values and run with em!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be this tree-field implementation.
It behaves just like a normal form field:

https://github.com/wencywww/Ext.ux.form.field.Tree

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a custom panel that extends an Ext Panel.  You can extend any component, check the docs for the fields, methods and events you can play with.

```
Ext.ns('yournamespace');

yournamespace.MyPanel = function(config) {
    yournamespace.MyPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
} 

Ext.extend(yournamespace.MyPanel, Ext.Panel, {

    myGlobalVariable : undefined,

    constructor : function(config) {
        yournamespace.MyPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, config);
    },

    initComponent : function() {
        this.comboBox = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            fieldLabel: "MyCombo",
            store: someStore,
            displayField:'My Label',
            typeAhead: true,
            mode: 'local',
            forceSelection: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText:'',
            selectOnFocus:true,
            tabIndex: 1,
            width: 200
        });

        // configure the grid
        Ext.apply(this, {
            listeners: {
                'activate': function(p) {
                    p.doLayout();
                 },
                 single:true
            },

            xtype:"form",
            border: false,
            layout:"absolute",
            labelAlign:"top",
            bodyStyle:"padding: 15px",
            width: 350,
            height: 75,

            items:[{
                xtype:"panel",
                layout:"form",
                x:"10",
                y:"10",
                labelAlign:"top",
                border:false,
                items:[this.comboBox]
            },
            {
                xtype:"panel",
                layout:"form",
                x:"230",
                y:"26",
                labelAlign:"top",
                border:false,
                items:[{
                    xtype:'button',
                    handler: this.someAction.createDelegate(this),
                    text: 'Some Action'
                }]
            }]
        }); // eo apply

        yournamespace.MyPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

        this.comboBox.on('select', function(combo, record, index) {
            this.myGlobalVariable = record.get("something");
        }, this);

    }, // eo function initComponent

    someAction : function() {
        //do something
    },

    getMyGlobalVariable : function() {
        return this.myGlobalVariable;
    }

}); // eo extend

Ext.reg('mypanel', yournamespace.MyPanel);
```

Comment: Yet another Ext 3 example when the OP asked for Ext 4.

Answer (score -2):

Could you describe the UI requirements that you have a bit more?  Are you sure that you even need to do build an entire field to support the TreePanel?  Why not set the value of a hidden field (see the "hidden" xtype in the API) from a click handler on a normal tree panel?

To answer your question more fully, you can find many tutorials on how to extend ExtJS components.  You do this by leveraging the Ext.override() or Ext.Extend() methods.

But my feeling is that you may be over-complicating your design.  You can achieve what you need to do by setting a value to this hidden field.  If you have complex data, you can set the value as some XML or JSON string.

**EDIT** Here's a few tutorials.  I highly recommend going with the KISS rule when it comes to your UI design.  Keep It Simple Stupid!
[Extending components using panels](http://dmitry-dulepov.com/article/making-custom-extjs-components-using-panels.html)

Comment: I wrote a new part to the question.

Comment: I have expressed requirement for custom fields so I can't ignore it. Maybe this is complicated but what I want to do is to push the  complicated parts into the lower levels of the application by making a new component and keeping the top levels simple by using this new component as an xtype or sg like this. 

Has it sense? I am searching for a good tutorial but I haven't found the ultimate one.

Comment: Again, this is an Ext 3 example, not Ext 4. There are massive differenced in the code syntax for the two versions of the framework.