# How to create a custom form field by grouping other form fields?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, extjs, extjs4

I want to group several standard form fields into a single custom form field in ExtJS 4. Basically, I want a category selector: when you select a category from the first combobox, a secondary combobox appears displaying its subcategories, and so on.

I've already written the logic for this and it's all encapsulated in a custom component that extends Ext.form.FieldSet. **But**, I want to use this component inside a form with records, so I'm guessing that I need to turn it into a field with functions like setValue, getValue and a validator. I found Ext.form.field.Base that offers all of this, but I can't find a way to combine the two components harmoniously (a container like Ext.form.FieldSet + a field like Ext.form.field.base).

Does anyone know if and how I can accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following solution may be not the best one. However it should work.

Extend `Ext.form.field.Base`. Then create `Ext.form.FieldSet` in `afterrender` handler and append it to field's `inputEl`. Then, of course, override field's `valueToRaw`, `setRawValue`, ...

Here is a code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.MyCoolField', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Base',
    requires: ['Ext.util.Format', 'Ext.XTemplate'], 
    fieldSubTpl: [  
        '<div id="{id}" class="{fieldCls}"></div>',
        {
            compiled: true,          
            disableFormats: true     
        }           
    ],

    isFormField: true,
    submitValue: true,
    afterRender: function() {
        this.callParent();

        this.fieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
            items: [{
              // ... config of the first item

              // The following configs should be set to false. It's important.
              // Otherwise form will assume this items as its fields
              isFormField: false,
              submitValue: false
        });
        this.fieldSet.render(this.inputEl);
    },

    // and here overriding valueToRaw and so on
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing. I don't know why but it has some rendering issues: The fieldset won't stretch to the container's full width, even when using an 100% anchor layout. I added an `Ext.apply(this, {listeners: {resize: function() {$this.container.doLayout();}}});` and it partially solves the problem. Hack hack hack. :) I'm going to mark this as accepted if no one else comes up with a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this in a different way, but disclaimer: it stopped working in extjs 4.1

I extended Ext.container.Container, then added Ext.form.field.Field as a mixin. From there I implemented getValue/setValue. It all worked great, but suddenly has a variety of issues in 4.1.

Comment: Could You post your code somewhere? This way maybe we all can get this working

Comment: I'm afraid I can't since I no longer work with that company and don't have the code anymore!

Comment: I could attempt to reproduce it at some point, but I haven't worked with EXTjs in a little while. It was honestly not very complex, though- basically as described above, the only "tricky" thing I did was to add Form.field.Field as a mixin, so the "aggregate" field could behave like a normal single field, once getValue and setValue were implemented. From there it's a relatively simple matter of dealing with the contained child Fields... I hope that helps! But I hope there is a better way, I've never found it.

Comment: Thanks for description :) I found solution that You just described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17059073/965722 I want to create custom form fields with more than one control in row. I found your post first, then thanks to Your description I found link that I attached :)