# Extjs defining custom field with getValue and setValue

Tags: extjs, custom-fields

I have defined a custom form field in ext js.
The custom field just contain a button (this button can be event some text or image, whatever).
I want to force my value. so I set the `getValue` to return some string.
The method is not invoked.
I want 2 things to happened.
1. `getValue` will be the value that will be sent in the submit.
2. `setValue` will give me the data that `form.load(...)` has loaded, and I will handle it my way...

here is an example, click on the submit and you'll see that `getValue` is not bee called. http://jsfiddle.net/RB9Hp/

or this more real life use-case : http://jsfiddle.net/FTV3R/ <- this will not send the value from getValue

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.CustomField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
    alias: 'widget.customfield',

    width: 300,
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([config]);
    },
    getValue : function(){
        console.log("getValue");
        return "test"; // I want to force new value.
    },
    setValue : function(val){},
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = ([{'xtype' : 'button',text : 'some button'}]);
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom ExtJS form field component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153362/how-to-create-custom-extjs-form-field-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ext.form.FieldContainer` is just container for form field components. If you need that your component will behave like form field it should use [`Ext.form.field.Field`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field) mixin. In documentation we can read that this mixin provides a common interface for the logical behavior and state of form fields, including:

- Getter and setter methods for field values
- Events and methods for tracking value and validity changes
- Methods for triggering validation

In your test case you also should change `getValue` to `getSubmitValue` because this method is used by form when it is collecting data from form fields after you call form's `submit()` method.

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.CustomField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
    alias: 'widget.customfield',
    mixins: {
        field: 'Ext.form.field.Field'
    },    

    width: 300,
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([config]);
    },
    getValue : function(){

        return "test"; // I want to force new value.
    },
    getSubmitValue: function() {
         return "test";
    },    
    setValue : function(val){},
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = ([{'xtype' : 'button',text : 'some button'}]);
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2vp**