# Automatic resizing of container panel containing custom ExtJS 4.2 form field?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-form

I have a custom field component based on `Ext.form.field.Base`. I got the big idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153362/how-to-create-custom-extjs-form-field-component/16964118#16964118). But what's bothering me with this solution is the fact, that it has a fixed height. What I would like to have instead is that the container grows in height as I add entries to the grid.

I have made an earlier attempt to make such a field but based on a Panel containing the grid and buttons. Putting this panel into a `vbox` layout and adding rows to the grid perfectly resized the container form panel. What did I miss to implement that the container would resize?

Here is a fiddle where you should easily see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/amx9j/

Comment: I think the problem may be that you are expecting resizing behavior when in reality if you add autoscroll, you will get a scrolling window inside a fixed window.  I spent sometime thinking about this and I'm not sure how to do what you want.  maybe a viewport?

Comment: Thanks Peter, for the input! I'm one step closer by using `updateLayout()` after setting the value. There is still a little layout problem with the grid running into overflow.

Comment: You might want to post on the extjs forums also. since it's been up here for a few days with no response, I think that's a reasonable thing to do.  Post a link to your question and I'll follow it there and if no answer try to get some attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working!

See this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/amx9j/3/

This configuration for the `form` worked:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'anchor',
    items: [{
        //custom fields that change their height
}]
```

And in the custom field you have to use `this.updateLayout()` everytime you expect the height to change. In addition I had to implement the `onResize` method:

```
onResize: function(w, h) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.grid.setWidth(w - this.getLabelWidth());
}
```

Important thing is, to NOT set the height of the grid ;-)

Thanks @Peter for taking the time to look into this!