# Sencha Architect: extend Ext.form.field.Picker

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

In Sencha Architect I want to extend the `Ext.form.field.Picker` to create a custom component. But the `Ext.form.field.Picker` is not in the available toolbox elements. Can I do it somehow?

I try to override the trigger field, and change the:

```
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger'
```

to

```
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker'
```

but it does nothing.

Comment: Refer following link, you may get some idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092112/ext-ux-form-field-datetime-questions

Comment: Create new 'class' which allows you to specify the extends attribute, unfortunately then not the 'picker' attributes.

or write your own by creating a js 'resource' and put it in your resources/ux folder.

Then you can call it eg:

Common.ux.picker.MyPicker

goes into resources/ux/picker/MyPicker.js

then hit the + (plus) next to loader on the 'application' node and add an item to the array {'MyApp:'.','Global':'resources'} and then the app will find your extension.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to build a component based on `Ext.form.field.Picker`. From the docs `Ext.form.field.Picker` is an abstract class and should not be used directly. Subclasses must implement the createPicker method to create a picker component appropriate for the field. Combobox, Date, Time etc. extend from this class. So you can use these to build your component.

Answer (score 0):

In your Sencha Architect (preferably version 3.1) click on the plus sign (top right corner) inside the Project Inspector, select Class and View.

You will get a new empty class being extended from `Ext.Base`. Change the extend property to `Ext.form.field.Picker` and you should get a popup asking "Would you like to transform this Class to a Ext.form.field.Picker, to enable full configuration and behavior". Click yes and you should be good to go.